# React and NodeJS: How can i send data from server to client?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I want to send responsed data from server to client. I use a NodeJS Server with NextJS and React.

I use this function on the server:

```js
function addEmailToMailChimp(email) {
    var request = require("request");
    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://XXX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/XXX/members',
        headers:
        {
            'Postman-Token': 'XXX',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            Authorization: 'Basic XXX=',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: { email_address: email, status: 'subscribed' },
        json: true
    };
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        //if (error) throw new Error(error);
        return body; //return the body Value
    });
    return request();
}
```

In the nested `request()` function i want to return the body value...
The function will be run from this point:

```js
server.post('/', (req, res) => {
            var MailChimpError = addEmailToMailChimp(req.body.email);
            console.log(MailChimpError); 
            res.send(MailChimpError); //send data to client
            res.end("success!");
        })
```

i try to save the return body Value inside the variable `MailChimpError` and try to show this variable in the Server Console. But it doesn't work. That's the first problem.

The second problem: I want to send the `MailChimpError` variable to the Client to show some error, if exits. On the Server i use the function `res.send(MailChimpError)`. My `handleSubmit()` function on the Client Side looks like this:

```js
handleSubmit() {
        const email = this.state.email;
        this.setState({email: ""});
        fetch('/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({email:email}),
          }).then((res)=> console.log(res.body)) //display the body value from server
      }
```

How can i do that? I have little experience in Node.js environments. I would be very grateful if you could show me concrete solutions. Thank you for your replies.

Comment: what value you are expecting in variable `MailChimpError`? Is it a return value from `request(options, function (error, response, body)`

Comment: ^^ ...and it *isn't* the value you return from the callback you pass into `request`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the right way to use the response from the function `addEmailToMailChimp` as it's an asynchronous function. For more examples, you can [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

I changed `addEmailToMailChimp` to accept a `callback` which I then passed to `request` as the second parameter which will be executed once the async operation has been finished.

```
var request = require("request");
function addEmailToMailChimp(email, callback) {

    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://XXX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/XXX/members',
        headers:
        {
            'Postman-Token': 'XXX',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            Authorization: 'Basic XXX=',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: { email_address: email, status: 'subscribed' },
        json: true
    };
    request(options, callback);
}
```

In your `server.js` file

```
server.post('/', (req, res) => {
    addEmailToMailChimp(req.body.email, (error, response, body) => {
        // This is the callback function which is passed to `addEmailToMailChimp`
        if(error){
            console.log('error', error);
            res.status(500).send({msg: 'Sorry, something went wrong :('})
        }
        else{
            res.status(200).send(response); //send data to client
        }

    });
})
```

Comment: All due respect, best to post a complete answer, not an incomplete answer followed by an edit.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Added - what I did and why

Comment: @SureshPrajapati thanks a lot for your changes. It works now :) Last question: How can i access the mesg: 'Sorry, something went wrong :(' for example, on the client side?